# How to change language part of URL by using regex in this example?

Tags: jquery, regex

Situation:

When an id element selected, get the current URl and change the /en/ part  to other language

current URL

http://127.0.0.1:5500/2023/en/activities_summary.html

I want to change it to

http://127.0.0.1:5500/2023/tc/activities_summary.html

code:

```
    $('#tc').on('click',function(){
           
              
            if(location.href.match(/\/(?:en|sc)\//)){
                location.replace(/^.+?\/(?:en|sc)\//,'tc') 
            }
        })
```

Comment: Maybe `location.href = location.href.replace(/\/(?:en|sc)\//, '/tc/')`, without any `if`?

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=\/\d{4}\/)` - your year part (4 digits)
`[a-z]{2}` - your language part (2 chars)
`(?=\/)` - closing slash part

```js
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/2023/en/activities_summary.html';

console.log(url.replace(/(?<=\/\d{4}\/)[a-z]{2}(?=\/)/, 'tc'));
```